# Square root of large matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, memory, large-data

I've been working with matrices size of 9GB and I've encountered the error of MATLAB cannot process the power operation `A^(-1/2)` (`mpower`) or the `sqrtm` function (then inverse). Size of `A` is 36000x36000. Is there anyway to work around this? 
Is anybody know the size limitation of `mpower`?

Comment: Can it take the inverse without problems? Is the matrix full?

Comment: What is the specific error message?

Comment: And what properties does the matrix `A` have? Diagonal? Symmetric? Etc.

Comment: I think your RAM usage is the problem. See the [documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sqrtm.html) on `sqrtm`; it creates quite a lot of root-matrices for one call. This probably means it tries to make so many matrices it does not fit into your memory.